# awk two wordlist files and get all words from second file which contains word from first

Tags: bash, awk

I'm new to bash. I have two wordlist files like following.

file1 (wordlist of searchwords)

```
foo
bar
```

file2 (wordlist with a lot of word combinations)

```
beforefoo
fooafter
beforefooafter
bar
```

I want to make a result file which contains the searchword from file1 and all words from file2 which contains the searchword like:

```
foo beforefoo fooafter beforefooafter
bar bar
```

I need a bash script to do this. File1 and file2 contains only one word per line, the number of lines of file1 is about 50.000 and file2 about 100.000.000 so I need a good script to do this as fast as possible.

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: What if one word from file1 does not have any match in file2? Do you still have to print it? Also, if you tagged with `awk` is because you are aware it is a good tool for this. What did you try so far?

Comment: No I don't want to list those searchwords which doesn't have match. I tagged with awk because when I was searching for a solution I saw that  there are scripts that do similar things, but I can't find out how to do exactly what I need. anubhava's solution works, but I would appreciate if we can add this rule to the script. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using awk:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]; next}
            {s=$1; for (i in a) if (index(i, $1)) s=s FS i; if (s!=$1) print s}' file2 file1
foo fooafter beforefoo beforefooafter
bar bar
```

Comment: Well done! I tried with `i ~ $1` but `index()` looks very nice as well. You can even use `FS` to specify the separator, instead of `" "`.

Answer (score 1):

Using awk

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$1;next}
{  for (i in a) if ($0~i) a[i]=a[i] FS $0}
END{for (i in a) print a[i]}' file1 file2
```

#### Explanation

- `NR==FNR{a[$1]=$1;next}` read the first file into associative array `a`
- `for (i in a) if ($0~i) a[i]=a[i] FS $0}`, attach second file's contents into `a`, if column #1 is index of `a`.
- `END{for (i in a) print a[i]` print the result from array
- use $1 because OP has mentioned one word each line, but maybe there are some whitespaces before and after these words, so with $1, it will be more accurated.

Comment: Note that the OP says it only has one word, so you can either do `$1` or `$0`. Also, I suggest you to give some explanations... it just appeared to me in the "low quality posts" review queue, I guess that was automatically added as it just being code.

Comment: @fedorqui , interesting things are, the accept answer has no explanation at all, and no one doubts it

Comment: Yes... don't know how it works. Maybe someone flagged it or it was just automatic. In any case, it is always useful to show some explanation, no matter what the others are doing. I would +1 again but I can't upvote twice :)